# Selenium IDE 1.2.0 is throwing errors with smartGWT 2.4

Tags: smartgwt, selenium-ide

I'm trying to create test cases with Selenium on a GUI built using smartGWT2.4 I have told Selenium where to find the user-extensions for both core and IDE. The problem is it keeps throwing a Unexpected Error Exception. It cannot find autWindow.isc. Then it points me to line 17 within the user-extensions.js. I've researched and could not find a solution to this problem. Is this a known problem, is there a solution? I can get Selenium to work if I roll back the IDE to a later version, but I wanted to use Webdriver. If anyone has any solutions please let me know.